# the SQL run much more slowly after using pg_pathman for table partitioning in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

the SQL run more slowly after using pg_pathman 1.5 for table partitioning in postgreSQL 9.6 ,the partitioning column is 'create_time' from tale T1 .the data range of column create_time is less than one month, and the SQL is as follows:

```
  SELECT
    t1.*
   FROM
     T1 t1
      JOIN T2 t2 ON t2.answer_question_id = t1.answer_question_id
      JOIN T3 t3 ON t3.answer_paper_id = t2.answer_paper_id
      JOIN T4 t4  ON t3.exam_paper_id = t4 .exam_paper_id
     WHERE
    t3.answer_paper_id = 'ab12-4567-7896-efgh'
   AND t1.create_time >= t4 .exam_begin_time AND t1.create_time <= t4 .exam_end_time
```

the table T1,T2,T3,T4 are defined as follows:

```
T1:(id,answer_question_id,create_time )
T2:(id,answer_question_id,answer_paper_id)
T3:(id,answer_paper_id,exam_paper_id )
T4:(id,exam_paper_id,exam_begin_time,exam_end_time)
```

I execute the following operation in pg_pathman:

1、table partitioning by column create_time :

```
 select                                             
    create_range_partitions('T1'::regclass,           
                        'create_time',                      
                        '2018-11-01 00:00:00'::timestamp,
                        interval '3 month',   
                        24,   
                        false) ;
```

2、data migration:

```
 select partition_table_concurrently('T1'::regclass,
                             10000,
                             1.0);
```

when I execute the sql above,it can not stop by itself,unless I cancel it manually after pg_pathman partitioning ,but it takes only 2 seconds to finish execution of the sql before pg_pathman partitioning the table T1, why is it?and how to fix this problem?

Comment: Postgres 9.6 didn't really support proper partitioning. If you really need it, you should upgrade to at least Postgres 12

Comment: Why do you think you need partitioning on the table? Do you want to make deleting old data more efficient? Partitioning is less of a performance tool, but more of a "data management" option.

Comment: I can't find such a version of pg_pathman.  Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: What is the execution plan for the slow query (`EXPLAIN <query text goes here>`)

Comment: You should upgrade your Postgres version to 12, not pg_pathman (with a current version, you don't really pg_pathman anymore to begin with)

Comment: Have you run `ANALYZE` on all the tables involved?

Comment: @jjanes execution plan is also too slowly，i could not even get the result of the execution plan.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver beg for a pardon

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but i can install the pg_pathman on the postgreSQL 9.9.6,and partition the table T1 to the 24 child tables successfully ,and managed to migrate the data of the parent table into the child tables completely.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if it updates to postgreSQL 12,is it simply just to update the version of postgreSQL from 9.6 to 12? the data format of postfreSQL 9.6 is compatible with postgreSQL 12

Comment: @jjanes you can search pg_pathman on the github

Comment: Sure, but when i do i don't find a v3.6 there.

Comment: @jjanes sorry,i wrote it wrongly,the version of pg_pathman i installed is 1.5

Comment: @jjanes i could not get the result of execution plan ,coz it need to run for a long time,i can not wait it to stop by itself

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name coz the table has more than 100 million data,i want to improve query and insert performance by partitioning table.

Answer (score 0):

i thought i have found a reason for it,the solution is that it needs to create index for the partitioning key (column),and use the partitioning column in the where clause of the SQL.